# Convert certain columns into dictionary python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I have a CSV file that looks more or less like this:

```
STUDENT_SUBJECT_AREA_VALUE  | STUDENT_LEVEL | HOST_INSTITUTION

222                           1               UK

58                            1               PT

222                           1               FR

223                           1               UK

222                           1               PT
```

What I need to do is take the values from the 'HOST_INSTITUTION' column and count how many times does that value appear. The output should be a dictionary like this:

```
{UK: 2, PT: 2, FR: 1}
```

I've tried to convert the CSV file into a dictionary but the file is very very big, and I only need that specific column. Is there a way to go through the CSV and read only the column I need?
I'm converting the CSV file to a dict like this:

```
def csv_to_dict(file_name):
   with open(file_name, 'rU') as file:
       reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=',')
       return [line for line in reader]
```

But this way I'm going through all the columns unnecessarilly. Feel free to ask any questions in case I wasn't very clear.

Answer (score 1):

The shell way: `awk '{print $3}' csv_file_path | sort | uniq -c`

Your csv file is delimitered with multiple space.

If you don't wanna use Counter:

```
def csv_to_dict(file_name):
    result = {}
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
        for row in reader:
            key = row[2]
            value = result.get(key, 0) + 1
            result[key] = value
    return result
```

`dict.get(key, default_value)`, if key doesn't exist, it will return default_value

```
In [25]: csv_to_dict(your_file_path)
Out[25]: {'FR': 1, 'PT': 2, 'UK': 2}
```

My csv file content:

```
STUDENT_SUBJECT_AREA_VALUE  | STUDENT_LEVEL | HOST_INSTITUTION
222                           1               UK
58                            1               PT
222                           1               FR
223                           1               UK
222                           1               PT
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting a list index out of range error in "key = row[2]"

Comment: @Stagg Sorry for my mistake. Your csv file is separated by multiple space. It's not the perfect csv format. Wait a minute

Comment: @Stagg Got it. Just add the `skipinitialspace` parameter.

Comment: @Stagg Inside your for loop you need to add a condition to check if the row(`if row:`) is empty. Basically, the OPs input file contains empty lines and that throws the exception

Comment: And if you use the same input file as the OP has shared even you would have faced the same exception

Comment: And also, the header is not ignored in your snippet!

Comment: I got the reason. Your csv file contains empty lines. I copied it and deleted the empty lines manually. If you want to handle it in python code. Follow @KeerthanaPrabhakaran to ignore empty line in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's really a performance bottleneck you'll probably want to read all columns to memory line by line. Unlike your solution this doesn't keep the entire CSV in memory but just the counts.

```
def csv_to_dict(file_name):
   cnt = Counter()
   with open(file_name, 'rU') as file:
       reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
       for row in reader:
            host_inst = row[2]
            cnt[host_inst] +=1
    return cnt

>>> csv_to_dict("my_file.txt")
Counter({'UK':2,"PT":2,"FR":1})
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting a list index out of range error in "key = row[2]"

Comment: @Stagg your CSV is probably not well structured. Can you paste the first 10 lines of it?

Comment: The CSV is very long, I donwloaded it from here : http://data.europa.eu/euodp/data/dataset/erasmus-mobility-statistics-2012-13.  It's the 'Raw data of Erasmus student mobility (study exchanges and work placements in 2012-13)' one.

Comment: can you provide the first 10 lines?

Answer (score 0):

For enhanced performance, you might want to try pandas. 
For example:

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.read_csv("bla.txt")
d.groupby("HOST_INSTITUTION").count(["STUDENT_SUBJECT_AREA_VALUE"].to_dict()
```

will produce the desired result :)

```
{'UK': 2, 'FR': 1, 'PT': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `data.csv` as your input file

```
STUDENT_SUBJECT_AREA_VALUE  | STUDENT_LEVEL | HOST_INSTITUTION

222                           1               UK

58                            1               PT

222                           1               FR

223                           1               UK

222                           1               PT
```

You can use `csv.DictReader()` to read your csv to dict
With that in hand, you can use `itemgetter` from `operator` module to get all the values with key name `HOST_INSTITUTION`.

```
import csv
def csv_to_dict(file_name='data.csv'):
    result = {}
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True,fieldnames=('STUDENT_SUBJECT_AREA_VALUE','STUDENT_LEVEL','HOST_INSTITUTION'))
        from operator import itemgetter
        res = map(itemgetter('HOST_INSTITUTION'),reader)[1:] #this will print ['UK', 'PT', 'FR', 'UK', 'PT']
        return {each:res.count(each)for each in set(res)}
print csv_to_dict()
```

Output

```
{'FR': 1, 'UK': 2, 'PT': 2}
```